# Failing to initialize a constant function pointer variable in class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance, initialization

So what I was going to do was:

```
class foo1{
    friend class foo3;
    int function1(string);
    string function2(int);
protected:
public:
};

class foo2:protected foo1{
protected:
public:
};

class foo3:protected foo2{
public:
    static constexpr function<string(int)> fptr1=function1;
};
```

By short word, I was trying to get access to a private function in foo1 by giving address of function1 to constant variable in foo3, fptr1. However, the compiler keeps giving me result of how it failed cast type of "function1" to what of fptr1. So, I wonder what is the problem in code?

I have tried re-casting the type by casting it to void* and casting it again to the function pointer type. However, it did not compile as well. Another attempt was just to follow compiler's advice, which made it compile, but the function didn't seemed to work. (The code was static constexpr void* fptr1=(void*)&function1;)

Comment: A member function from a class is NOT a  `std::function<std::string(int)>`. The only way to make it a function is to have an INSTANCE of foo1 and then use a lambda expression to initialize your function. And since you need a runtime instance fptr1 cannot be constexpr (also fptr is NOT a function pointer... it is a std::function).

Comment: Another member functions are not the same as non-member functions question. Member functions have access to the member variables for the object they are called on. How do you think they get this access if they are just the same as regular functions?

Comment: You could make`function1` static, then it becomes just like a regular function. Note that your parameter type and return type are the wrong way around in the code above, but I guess that is just a typo.

Comment: Because `function1` is private, you cannot use it outside `foo1`. If not private you can store its value using its real type `static constexpr int (foo1::*fptr1)(string) = &foo1::function1;`.

Answer (score 0):

A member function in class can access class member variables. It has an independent address in the instantiation of the class, which is not constant. If you want to use it in your way, declare the function as static.

The code below uses typedef to define function type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class foo1{
    friend class foo3;
    static int function1(string str) { cout << str; return 0;}
    string function2(int);
protected:
public:
};

class foo2:protected foo1{
protected:
public:
};

class foo3:protected foo2{
public:
    typedef int (*func_type) (string);
    static constexpr func_type fptr1 = foo1::function1; // Add class namespace before function name.
};


int main()
{
    foo3 f3;
    f3.fptr1("test f3.fptr1.\n");
    return 0;
}
```